# mod_rewrite lexical comparison

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

NOTE: following code is surrounded by a RewriteCond/RewriteRule that skips the cases so they do not get ran again after the redirect takes place.

Why can't I get this to test true?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ="/unique/test/test"
RewriteRule ^.*$ /match [R=301,L]
```

I'm outputing everything with the following line and I can clearly see what REQUEST_FILENAME is:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /test$1-filename-%{REQUEST_FILENAME}-URI-%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but I can't get it to match.

I was originally trying to do something like this to test if had modified the path from the original URI or not, but seeing as I cannot get the above to test true, this certainly does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} =%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `RewriteCond`, variables are only expanded within the first argument. So with your `RewriteCond` you are actually comparing the value of *REQUEST_FILENAME* with the literal string `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

To do what you intended, you need to do some trick:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]+)#\1$
```

Comment: Thanks, if I understand this correctly this condition is comparing REQUEST_FILENAME#REQUEST_URI to REQUEST_FILENAME#REQUEST_FILENAME giving me the comparison I wanted REQUEST_URI to REQUEST_FILENAME.

Comment: Is there a mistake above?  Shouldn't the pipe be a pound?